# How to output system print out in IBM Designer eclipse debugger console

Tags: lotus-domino

How to output system print out in IBM Designer eclipse debugger console
[image]

it does not show the system.out in the console

Comment: System.out.println should appear on the domino console or there in the notes client/designer client there is also the Tools\Java Debug Console